# how to compare dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select dates bigger than in javascript function. My function return empty array and I don't know wher I'm doing mistake

```
var arr = ["2018-01-24T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-25T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-
26T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-27T17:43:03.000Z"]
var biggerThanElements = arr.filter(x=>{
  x = new Date(x);
  element = new Date("2018-01-23T00:00:00.000Z");
  x > element
});
```

console.log(biggerThanElements)

Comment: You need an explicit `return` when using `{}` in an anonymous function don't you?

Comment: If you're not averse to external libraries I highly recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) when working with dates and times.

Comment: no you don't need a library.. youre doing it exactly right you just forgot to return..

Comment: `return x > element`

Comment: (Don't forget to declare `element`.)

Comment: Instead of using plain javascript for date manipulations using moment js.
    Please refer below url for you refrence
    https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/rzyz4wgp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just compare directly with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates/time strings.

```js
var arr = ["2018-01-24T17:43:03.000Z", "2018-01-25T17:43:03.000Z", "2018-01-26T17:43:03.000Z", "2018-01-27T17:43:03.000Z"],
    biggerThanElements = arr.filter(x => x > "2018-01-23T00:00:00.000Z");

console.log(biggerThanElements);
```

Comment: this might not work if the date come from different sources as there are a few variables.. for example, the standard allows the ommision of the "T" or a "+00" instead of the "Z"

Comment: the data should follow the same standard for comparison ...

Answer (score 1):

You missed your return statement for change to  `return x > element`

```js
var arr = ["2018-01-24T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-25T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-26T17:43:03.000Z","2018-01-27T17:43:03.000Z"]
var biggerThanElements = arr.filter(x=>{
  x = new Date(x);
  element = new Date("2018-01-23T00:00:00.000Z");
   return x > element
});
console.log(biggerThanElements)
```